# Entity Framework - list of items is not loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to save games in database with EntityFramework Code-First.

There are fragments of my classes:

```
/// <summary>
/// Game class
/// </summary>
public class Game : ObservableObject
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int GameId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// List of teams
    /// <see cref="Models.Teams"/>
    /// </summary>
    public Teams Teams
    {
        get
        {
            return teams;
        }
        set
        {
            teams = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Teams");
        }
    }
}


/// <summary>
/// Teams class
/// </summary>
public class Teams : ObservableObject, IEnumerable<Team>
{
    public int GameId { get; set; }

    public Game Game { get; set;}

    List<Team> teamsList = new List<Team>();

    /// <summary>
    /// List of teams
    /// </summary>
    public List<Team> TeamsList
    {
        get
        {
            return teamsList;
        }
        set
        {
            teamsList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TeamsList");
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Team (group of players)
/// </summary>
public class Team : ObservableObject
{


    #region Properties & fields

    List<Player> players = null;
    static int NumberOfTeams = 0;

    /// <summary>
    /// List of players in team
    /// </summary>
    public List<Player> Players
    {
        get
        {
            return players;
        }
        set
        {
            players = value;

            OnPropertyChanged("NumberOfPlayers");
            OnPropertyChanged("IsEmpty");
            OnPropertyChanged("IsNotDefault");
            OnPropertyChanged("Players");
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
///Defines player
/// </summary>
public class Player : Models.Person
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Identifies player in game. Also lets to recover player's statistics from last month
    /// </summary>
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
}
```

And the Entity Framework part:

```
 public class GameContext : DbContext
{
    public GameContext() : base("Db")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
    }

    public DbSet<Models.Game> Games { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //Configure domain classes using modelBuilder here

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Models.Devices>().HasKey(d => d.GameId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Models.Players>().HasKey(p => p.TeamId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Models.Teams>().HasKey(t => t.GameId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Models.Scenario>().HasKey(s => s.GameId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Models.Game>().HasOptional<Models.Teams>(g => g.Teams).WithRequired(t => t.Game);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Models.Game>().HasOptional<Models.Scenario>(g => g.Scenario).WithRequired(s => s.Game);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Models.Game>().HasOptional<Models.Devices>(g => g.Devices).WithRequired(d => d.Game);

    }
}
 public static class GameService
{
    public static List<Models.Game> GetGames()
    {
        using (var gctx = new Contexts.GameContext())
        {
            return gctx.Games.ToList();
        }
    }

    public static void InsertGame(Models.Game game)
    {
        using (var gctx = new Contexts.GameContext())
        {
            gctx.Games.Add(game);
            gctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use it all like this:

```
List<Models.Game> games = Services.GameService.GetGames().ToList();

        foreach(var game in games)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Game " + game.GameId);

            foreach (var team in game.Teams)
            {
                Console.Write("\t");
                Console.WriteLine("Team" + team.Number);
                foreach(var player in team.Players)
                {
                    Console.Write("\t\t");
                    Console.WriteLine("Player" + player.PlayerId);
                }
            }
        }
```

When I run this code i see my games, teams for that games, but i can't reach players for each team. So my question is: what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: If you have disabled lazy loading then you have to load related entities explicitly with `Include` method (`using System.Data.Entity`). For more datails on using `Include` you can take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Nice you got it working! The reason why Lazy Loading would not work here is that you dispose your DbContext in the service after getting your data and do a ToList(). So any later access to any data not eagerly loaded in your list would not work (the context is not there anymore, no valid connection).  By doing Eager Loading with explicit includes you solve that. But notice that you have to load all data in every game every time you want to use any part of it (that's the price of eager loading). It could cause you scale problems in the future.

Comment: @Diana I know it causes problems in most issues, but in my case it does not matter that much, because I have to save only few games.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I resolved my problem. There were few reasons which caused the problem.

1. Need to use **Include** for Eager Loading. Method looks like that:

   ```
   public static List<Models.Game> GetGames()
   {
       using (var gctx = new Contexts.DatabaseContext())
       {

           return gctx.Games.Include(g => g.Teams).Include(g => g.Teams.TeamsList.Select(t => t.Players)).ToList();
       }
   }
   ```
2. I used **Fluent API** to determine relationships (overriding DatabaseContext.OnModelCreating):

   ```
   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {

       modelBuilder.Entity<Models.Game>().HasOptional(g => g.Teams).WithOptionalPrincipal(t => t.Game); // 1 -> 0..1
       modelBuilder.Entity<Models.Game>().HasOptional(g => g.Devices).WithOptionalPrincipal(d => d.Game); // 1 -> 0..1
       modelBuilder.Entity<Models.Game>().HasOptional(g => g.Scenario).WithOptionalPrincipal(s => s.Game); // 1-> 0..1

       modelBuilder.Entity<Models.Teams>().HasMany(ts => ts.TeamsList).WithRequired(t => t.Teams); // 1 -> many
       modelBuilder.Entity<Models.Team>().HasMany(t => t.Players).WithRequired(p => p.Team); // 1 -> many

       base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);


   }
   ```
3. Only in Game class navigation properties are NOT virtual.

Thanks for any help in this case. You're wonderful, guys!

Answer (score 1):

You should add the `virtual` keyword to your navigation properties, that is, the properties that will be automatically filled by EF. Specially if you are using lazy loading. If a property is not declared as virtual then EF will not be able to replace it by a proxy, and so the lazy loading will not work. You will not get exceptions, but the data will not be loaded. Try that with the `Players` list property:

```
public virtual List<Player> Players
```

Also, your model is a bit strange. The keys in the entities are supposed to be identifiers for the entity itself, something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Game>().HasKey(g => g.GameId);
modelBuilder.Entity<Team>().HasKey(t => t.TeamId);
modelBuilder.Entity<Player>().HasKey(p => p.PlayerId);
```

That is because they will be the primary keys for those entities. You are using them instead more like foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework lazy loads objects.

That is, it doesn't actually load each Player object in the Team object within the Game object. Rather it returns a proxy to it.

Try returning an `IQueryable` in the `GetGames()` method:

```
public static class GameService
{
    public static IQueryable<Models.Game> GetGames()
    {
        using (var gctx = new Contexts.GameContext())
        {
            return gctx.Games.Select(....);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What should `.Select()` do?

Comment: @dotctor It returns them all as a queryable item of type `Game`. Thus you can query the required properties you desire.
In your example, if at a later stage @Terrykk adds more properties to the Player object, then you will have to go back and explicitly add they also. Where as queryable, as soon as you query them, it will load the values you require.

Comment: I turned off lazy loading in GameContext constuctor

Comment: Select without any arguments? why I can't use it?

Comment: Sorry, In the select you would have to put some logic such as `Select(x => !x.GameAlreadyPlayed);` > You will then have all the upcoming games that haven't played yet;
Alternatively `Select(x => x);`

Is there any particular reason that you want lazy loading off?

Comment: I want save in database only few games which are in progress. There's no reason to lazy load them.

Comment: I would turn lazy loading back on. For your application it won't make too much of a difference especially if you are working with only a few games. EF defaults lazy loading to on, so unless you explicitly don't want it, I would just keep it.
It will make your life a lot easier especially if your model changes or if you add more as you won't need to append to your `.Include(g => g.XXXX)` statements.

Comment: Consider risks of having lazy loading enabled. It depends on your requirements (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853(v=vs.113).aspx#8)

Comment: I turned on lazy loading,but I still have exceptions 
    "Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'Game_Teams_Target' of the relationship 'Contexts.Game_Teams' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1."

Comment: I see you have done some of the model building in your datacontext but still haven't done them all such as modelbuilder.HasMany(T => T.Players);

Answer (score 0):

I'm also migrating from ASPNET MVC 5 to .NET Core 6

1. Search your whole project for `: DbContext`, it will find your data context class.
2. Notice that this class found also has some methods that return `DBSet`. These are the Models that represent tables in the database and you can access those directly.
3. Import your data context class as a private property of your controllers like:

   private readonly SampleDbContext _context;
4. Access your models (DBSets) with chained methods. Query example to return single user:

   _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Name == input.Name);